# Can ANTLR return Lines of Code when lexing?

Tags: antlr, lexical-analysis, lines-of-code

I am trying use ANTLR to analyse a large set of code using full Java grammar. Since ANTLR needs to open all the source files and scan them, I am wondering if it can also return lines of code.

I checked API for Lexer and Parser, it seems they do not return LoC. Is it easy to instrument the grammar rule a bit to get LoC? The full Java rule is complicated, I don't really want to mess a large part of it.

Comment: You could just run unix/cygwin wc, if all you want to know is lines in the file.  That's obviously not the same as "lines of code" but that number is notoriously flaky; a file with one token per source line likely has a huge "source line" count, but it isn't real.  You're better off actually parsing, and counting something like "statements", which is independent of layout.

Comment: @IraBaxter Thanks. 'Lines of code' should also include class declaration, import statement, etc. I am currently counting LoC in another passing. I am wondering if I can directly get it easily in the ANTLR passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing ANTLR grammar, and want to count certain things during parsing, you could do something like this:

```
grammar ExistingGrammar;

// ...

@parser::members {
  public int loc = 0;
}

// ...

someParserRule
 : SomeLexerRule someOtherParserRule {loc++;}
 ;

// ...
```

So, whenever your oparser encounters a `someParserRule`, you increase the `loc` by one by placing `{loc++;}` after (or before) the rule.

So, whatever your definition of a *line of code* is, simply place `{loc++;}` in the rule to increase the counter. Be careful not to increase it twice:

```
statement
 : someParserRule {loc++;}
 | // ...
 ;

someParserRule
 : SomeLexerRule someOtherParserRule {loc++;}
 ;
```

### EDIT

I just noticed that in the title of your question you asked if this can be done during lexing. That won't be possible. Let's say a LoC would always end with a `';'`. During lexing, you wouldn't be able to make a distinction between a `';'` after, say, an assignment (which is a single LoC), and the 2 `';'`s inside a `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }` statement (which wouldn't be 2 LoC).

Answer (score 0):

In the C target the data structure ANTLR3_INPUT_STREAM has a getLine() function which returns the current line from the input stream. It seems the Java version of this is  CharStream.getLine(). You should be able to call this at any time and get the current line in the input stream.

Comment: LoC is probably not just the line number: why would s/he else bother with a parser if the requirement would simply have been to count the number of new lines?

Comment: correct @BartKiers but the grammar you given above doesn't seems to work with antlr4 grammar. Do you have something which will give us exact source lines of code and ignore the comment lines and the blank lines. ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a visitor to visit the CompilationUnit context, then context.stop.getLine() will give you the last line number of the compilation unit context.

```
@Override public Integer visitCompilationUnit(@NotNull JAVAParser.CompilationUnitContext ctx) {
    return ctx.stop.getLine();
}
```

Comment: Nope that will never be lines of code . It will have blank lines and comment lines as well.